# Why I can't enable select html after disabling it?

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this code? When I change first select to International It disables the second select. but when I'm select Local it doesn't enable the second select

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetextbox()
{
    if (document.getElementById("LocalOrInternations").value == "International") {
        document.getElementById("NormalOrPaper").disabled='true';
    } 
  else
     document.getElementById("NormalOrPaper").disabled='false';
}
</script>

<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Local Or International</span>
<select name="LocalOrInternations" id="LocalOrInternations" onChange="changetextbox();" class="form-control">
    <option  value="Local">Local</option>
    <option value="International">International</option>
</select>

<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Normal Or Paper Seminar></span>
<select name="NormalOrPaper" id="NormalOrPaper" class="form-control">
    <option  value="Normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="Seminar">Seminar</option>
</select>
```

[Code test](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEXSB4Z4TPHG)

Comment: `.disabled= true`/ `.disabled= false`  not `'true'`

Comment: Assign boolean value `true/false` for disabled property

Comment: @chiragpatel: No, when dealing with the **property** (as the OP is), setting it to `false` is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'false'` and `'true'` are **strings**. When coerced to boolean, they're both `true` (because any string that isn't blank is "truthy".) You want the actual booleans `false` and `true` (no quotes).

```
if (document.getElementById("LocalOrInternations").value == "International") {
    document.getElementById("NormalOrPaper").disabled = true;
    // -------------------------------------------------^^^^
} 
else {
    document.getElementById("NormalOrPaper").disabled = false;
    // -------------------------------------------------^^^^^
}
```

---

Side note: I recommend being consistent with your `{}`. Either include them around single statements (as you did with the `if`), or don't (as you did with the `else`), but don't *sometimes* include them around single statements and not other times.

Comment: Thanks very much, in this mistake, I feel like I'm in the first programming class. It's happened.

Comment: @khorshid: We're all new at things at first! :-)

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove `'` from the boolean tag.

you have to set like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetextbox()
{
    if (document.getElementById("LocalOrInternations").value == "International") {
        document.getElementById("NormalOrPaper").disabled=true;
    } 
  else
     document.getElementById("NormalOrPaper").disabled=false;
}
</script>
```

check this jsfiddle:[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/xf1up1ps/)

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
document.getElementById("NormalOrPaper").removeAttribute('disabled');
```

Comment: That *does* work, but using the property (as the OP is) is cleaner and simpler.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I agree, but I now tend to use removeAttribute as a catch-all as I've experienced problems in the past with some browsers (is it time to mention IE now?)

Comment: @TonyDuffill: That's interesting. I've never had trouble with IE when dealing with properties. I *have* when dealing with attributes. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, thank you for correcting - you're clearly tons more experienced than me. Looking back at my notes, it is indeed attributes that  sometimes need removing before you can reset them in IE (and probably only 7/8/9? - I'm guessing).